# Integral $f(x)=\int_0^1(u^2+ux)(x^2+2ux)^{n-2}du$

Tags: calculus

I have a function: $$f(x)=\int_0^1(u^2+ux)(x^2+2ux)^{n-2}du$$
I tried to evaluate  the above definite integral by using integration by parts and as per my calculations

\begin{equation}
f(x)=\frac{x^{n-2}(1+x)(2+x)^{n-1}}{2(n-1)}-\frac{1}{4x^2n(n-1)}[x^n(x+2)^{n+1}-x^{2n+1}]-\frac{1}{4x^3n(n^2-1)}[(x^2+2x)^{n+1}-x^{2n+2}]
\end{equation}
i would be highly obliged if someone can tell me if my calculations are correct.i tried to plug in the integral in the MATHEMATICA  as well but i sould not get anything.thankig you in anticipation.

Comment: This site can sometimes work out exact steps and may help [Symbolab Step-by-Step Calculator](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/integration%20%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B1%7D%20%5Cleft(u%5E%7B2%7D%2Bu%5Ccdot%20x%5Cright)%5Cleft(x%5E%7B2%7D%2B2u%5Ccdot%20x%5Cright)%5E%7Bn-2%7Ddu)

Comment: This  is the answer given by $ f(x)=\frac{1}{8x^3}[(x^2+2x)^{n+1}-\frac{x^{2n+2}}{n+1}-x^4(\frac{(x^2+2x)^{n-1}}{n-1}-\frac{{x^{2n-2}{n-1})]$